# Mysql, phpmyadmin, create database

Tags: php, mysql, database, phpmyadmin

I am currently having an issue where a template script needs me to edit the db name, username, and password. I have created a database, however I can't seem to find a way to create a username/password, any suggestions? Additionally, I am using version 3.5.1, released earlier today.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`CREATE USER`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/create-user.html) to create a user, and [`GRANT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/grant.html) to grant access to the server, databases, and/or tables.

That, or modify the tables in the `mysql` database and flush privileges. But don't do that.

Comment: Did you find the box that lets you enter SQL queries?

Comment: Yes I did. I haven't have hardly ever used phpmyadmin, but I would not suggest updating to the new gui, for newbies such as myself who read this.

Answer (score 0):

What hosting service do you use?  I have a Yahoo web service and in order for me to create a new user, I have to create it in PHPMyAdmin but to set the password, I have to go the the Yahoo webmaster control panel (after creating user).  Backwards and more complicated than it needs to be but this could be a similar situation with your web host

**EDIT**

Additionally, Yahoo prevents me from using `CREATE` to create a new database from script; I can only do this though phpMyAdmin.  Again, this could be a similar situation preventing your from running this script.

Comment: XAMPP As of right now, but tommowrow I hope to have it uploaded to my site host by 000webhost